# CakePHP 1.3 Use count on subchilds in paginator

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, paginator

I'm working on a very old project to make some improvements on the paginator. We have an `UsedAd` object, with `UsedItem` childs. How can I make sure to only load the `UsedAd` objects with childs. So I want to exclude the UsedItem objects without UsedItem childs.

Here's the current code:

```
public $paginate = array(
        'UsedAd' => array(
            'limit' => 15,
            'order' => 'created ASC',
           // 'fields' => array('UsedAd.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM used_items AS UsedItem WHERE UsedItem.used_ad_id = UsedAd.id) AS total_used'),
           // 'conditions' => array('total_used > 0'),
            'contain' => array(
                'UsedItem' => array(
                    'ItemBrand' => array(
                        'className' => 'Catalog.ItemBrand',
                        'foreignKey' => 'brand_id'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    );
```

I tried to use a subquery, but this isn't working (throws an unknown column error). You can see my tries in two lines which are commented.